# Login security - client side salt - How are people creating this per-user public parameter?

Tags: security, client, salt

Because the client side salt value should be a per-user parameter and it's publicly visible on the client side (I don't see a way to hide it), how are people determining what this value should be?  I'm **not** asking HOW to do it (i.e js library, etc.).  I know that my db and its salt value has to be the same as the client side salt but where are you coming up with this value?  Some portion of the username?  This is the only value I can see being consistent between the client side and the db, but I'm not sure.  Any thoughts?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've never heard of performing salting (or any password operation, really) in the client. Although the salt is not a truly secret value, knowledge of it can make attacks on that particular password easier. Why do you want to perform salting client-side?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I guess maybe I'm confused?  If I have salted + hashed my password in the db, but do not salt + hash the login password before sending down the wire, how do I successfully match the values?  Despite using SSL, I'm trying not to send plain text passwords.  Am I going about this wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Sending a plaintext password via SSL is perfectly fine: the communications channel is secure. *Storing* a plaintext (or even reversibly encrypted) password is a huge no-no, but transmission of one over what can be safely assumed to be a secure channel is generally fine. Any client-side salting scheme would expose knowledge of the salt to the client and thus in theory to the attacker.

Comment: To clarify: Salting the password in the DB is largely to protect against an attacker getting a copy of the DB, and then using dictionaries and/or rainbow tables to narrow the search space against the hashed passwords. The salt is actually stored next to the password as plaintext, and is simply concatenated to the plaintext password before hashing. It wouldn't make a brute-force attack any harder, it just turns dictionary attacks into brute-force attacks. Security of the password in-transit is up to SSL, not up to salting.

Comment: Gotcha.  I misunderstood the use of salting, etc.  Thanks for clarification.